# Get mp3 url from html page using preg_match_all

Tags: php, regex

I'm attempting to extract mp3 link from html page but my preg_match_all isn't working?

Sample of HTML on page from PHP CURL

```
keyEnabled: true,
remainingDuration: true,
toggleDuration: true,
ready: function (event) {
    $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        title: "",
        mp3: "http://example.com/vod/test.mp3",
    });
}
```

I want to get `http://example.com/vod/test.mp3`.

```
$Pattern = '/((https?:\/\/)?(\w+?\.)+?(\w+?\/)+\w+?.(mp3|ogg))/im';
preg_match_all($Pattern,htmlentities($html),$Matches);
var_dump($Matches);
```

Nothing is returned, how do I do this ?

Example page:  https://3v4l.org/G4sLF

Comment: Your code is working for me

Comment: Same https://3v4l.org/clk2T

Comment: Can you dump the content of `$html` ?

Comment: @executable check this:  https://3v4l.org/G4sLF  nothing returned

Comment: @JonStirling here is an updated sample page, nothing returned  https://3v4l.org/G4sLF

Comment: It's working if the url is `http://example.com/vod/test.mp3`

Comment: How come?  This is the url i want "http://ns1.indexforce.com/vod/barg-i_sabz_1.mp3"  , why won't it return this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your URL you have a dash `-` that is not included in `\w`

```
http://ns1.indexforce.com/vod/barg-i_sabz_1.mp3
//                         here __^
```

Use this regex:

```
$Pattern = '~mp3:\h+"((https?://)?\S+\.(mp3|ogg))"~im';
```

Comment: I think you should also match where there is `mp3 :` before

Comment: @executable: You're right, updated